# Process Killed For Excesive Resource Usage

Tags: php, process, dreamhost

Today I was testing some scripts in console that seemed to have issues server side, and for a certain file I got the following advice:

> Yikes! One of your processes (php, pid 15278) was just killed for excessive resource usage.
>   Please contact DreamHost Support for details.

Ok, got it, I should upgrade my hosting, but I´m not clear about why sometimes it happens with apparently much more resource usage.

The piece of code, handling the file that causes the error, generates that otuput:

```
Iteration 1 Start
Memory Usage At the Start: 31,179.26Kbytes //Got with memory_get_usage
Memory Usage At the End: 26,350.64Kbytes
Duration:14
Iteration 2 Start

Yikes! One of your processes (php, pid 15278) was just killed for excessive resource usage.
Please contact DreamHost Support for details.
```

However, using another file ( a bigger one ) I get the following log:

```
Iteration 1 Start
Memory Usage At the Start: 132,115.70Kbytes
Memory Usage At the End: 26,350.64Kbytes: 129,268.95Kbytes
Duration:34
Iteration 2 Start
Memory Usage At the Start: 131,368.04Kbytes
Memory Usage At the End: 129,287.41Kbytes
Duration:36
....
```

And so on....

And the question is, why I always get the same error for the 1st file, that seems to use much less memory, while the second one finishes its 12 iterations without a single problem? Any guess?

**UPDATE: CODE ADDED**

```
foreach ( $worksheets as $worksheet ){  
        $this->ultimo_apunte = NULL;
            for ( $i=1; $i < $worksheet["totalRows"]; $i+=self::$chunk_size ){
                echo "\Iteration".(($i-1)/250+1);
                $comienzo_iteracion = time();
                $filter = new ExcelReadFilter($i, self::$chunk_size);
                $reader->setReadFilter($filter);            
                $objPHPExcel = $reader->load($excel_file);
                $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndexByName($worksheet["worksheetName"]);
                $sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,false,true);
                $c = 0;

                foreach ( $sheetData as $rowIndex => $row ){
                    if (!isset($apunte)) {
                        $apunte = Apunte::conFila($row);    
                        if ( $apunte->completo() ){
                            $apunte->ejercicio = "N/A";
                            fwrite($f, $apunte->insert_stmt());
                            $this->ultimo_apunte = $apunte;
                            unset($apunte);
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        $apunte->completar($row);

                        if ( $apunte->completo() ){
                            $apunte->ejercicio = "N/A";
                            fwrite($f, $apunte->insert_stmt());
                            $this->ultimo_apunte = $apunte;
                            unset($apunte);
                        }
                    }
                }
echo "\nMemory Usage At the Start: ".number_format((memory_get_usage()/1024), 2)."Kbytes";  
                unset($sheetData);
                unset($objPHPExcel);    


echo "\nMemory Usage At the End: ".number_format((memory_get_usage()/1024), 2)."Kbytes";

                $fin_iteracion = time();
                $it_duration = $fin_iteracion - $comienzo_iteracion;
                $iteraciones_completadas+=1; 

                if ( !$process ) {
                    $process = new stdClass;
                    $process->start_time = date("Y-m-d");
                }

                if ( $iteraciones_completadas == 0 ){
                    $process->ellapsed_time = 0;
                }else{
                    $process->ellapsed_time = $fin_iteracion - strtotime($process->start_time);
                }

                $process->estimated_time = $process->ellapsed_time+$it_duration*($num_iteraciones - $iteraciones_completadas);
echo "\nDuration:".$it_duration."";
//log_string(ob_get_contents());        
//ob_clean();
                if ( method_exists($process, "saveToFile" )) $process->saveToFile();
        }
    }
    fclose($f);

global $db;

        $sql = "
            LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$db->real_escape_string($sql_file)."' 
            INTO TABLE apuntes
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
            ENCLOSED BY '".'"'."' 
            ESCAPED BY '\\\'  
            LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'
            (id_diario, fecha, asiento, apunte, cuenta, descripcion, concepto, debe, haber, es_apertura, es_cierre, ejercicio);
        ";

        error_reporting(0);
        $db->query($sql);
```

Sorry for the mess....

Comment: Telepathy not working, please post code.

Comment: Didn´t post the code before because I thought it could distract the question I´m asking, and not help too much. I assume that sooner or  later I will need to upgrade my hosting plan, it was more curiosity about why with less resources I don´t get the error, but I will edit and post the code

Comment: Btw, reducing the chunk size from 5000 to 250 worked, but I don´t know yet why the difference.

Comment: My bad, it didn´t fix the problem, just delayed it long enough to make me think it was fixed. When it went to iteration number  52 died again. Memory usage before the unset kept growing all the time at a small rate, and going back to normal after the unset, what is kinda weird. It looks like the phpexcel reader needs to open the file to the row it´s going to read